# ObjectBox - Database Backup/Restore

Tags: objectbox

I have gone through the documentation and code for sample app, and figured out that files/objectbox/objectbox/data.mdb is the default file where all data is stored.

Assuming my understanding is correct, I have a couple of questions that I couldn't find documentation on:

1. I want to have a backup/restore functionality in my Android app. Assuming I use native SQLite DB, I know I can upload the .sqlite file to cloud, and then download it on the same (or even a different) device to restore it. 
   Can the same be done with data.mdb file?
2. How about lock.mdb? Do I need to copy\upload it along with data.mdb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ensure that the file is not opened (e.g. by any BoxStore) to enforce a consistent state of the data.mdb file for backup.
2. The lock.mdb file is not relevant for backups

Comment: Thanks for the response. I played around it with it while waiting for the response (which by he way pretty quick, thanks), and figured it out. Best.

Comment: What is lock.mdf file? What is it's purpose? Why is it generated other than data.mdb file?

Comment: The  lock.mdb file keeps track of internal stuff, e.g. coordinating "reader" resources. It does not contain application data.